# How to completely remove the little ease effect on moodular (jquery slideshow)?

Tags: jquery, slideshow, easing

I guess all is in the title.
Even without specifying an easing method, the sliding element slows down before finishing the sliding movement.
I would like to remove that. Do you know how I could do that?

moodular url : http://www.gougouzian.fr/projects/jquery/moodular/index.php

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the doc from your link :

```
var moodular = jQuery("#myCarousel").moodular({
        controls        : 'keys',
        effects         : 'fade',
        speed           : 500,
        dispTimeout     : 1000,
        auto            : false,
        api             : true
});
```

customise your easing
(http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html)

```
var moodular = jQuery("#myCarousel").moodular({
        easing          : 'linear',
        effects         : 'fade',
        speed           : 500

});
```